# Sending email via exchange server issue. (system.net.mail vs microsoft.exchange.webservices)

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchange-server

I am developing a web application for my company. Part of it requires the internal user to fill out a form, and send an email on this user's behalf. It is all within the company. I searched and found two possible routes old system.net.mail and a more recent microsoft.exchange.webservices, but seems our exchange server requires credentials. I can only get the user's login and his email address login+"@company.com". How can i get this done?

Below are the codes i used smtp (system.net.mail), but it doesnt work.

```
            string[] username =System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\');
            string email = username[1] + "@company.com";
            MailAddress from = new MailAddress(email);
            MailAddress to = new MailAddress("someone@company.com");
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);                
            message.Subject = "testmail";
            message.Body = "<h>testmail</h>";
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.Send(message);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SmtpClient requires that you either specify the SMTP server directly, or that you have the right application/machine configuration settings for it to detect the server automatically. Your code is choosing the second option implicitly, and I suspect you don't have the right settings in app/machine config. Exchange does NOT support SMTP in its default configuration, afaik, so unless someone familiar with your Exchange server knows SMTP is configured and can give you the right address, SmtpClient is probably out.

Exchange Web Services (aka EWS) is probably your better answer, but it's not really a good one. In order to use exchange web services, you will need one of:

1) The domain, username, and password of the user so that you can pass the right NetworkCredential to EWS. In your case, this would probably mean the user has to enter their password into your form, which may break your requirements.

2) The user that the process is running as (in a web application, the application pool identity for IIS) has to have permissions to send mail as the user in question.

3) If you can use ASP.NET authentication to impersonate the user (this would only be a good approach in a LAN application), then you can effectively fall back to option (2), because now you will be talking to EWS as the user, who obviously will have permission to send mail from their own address.

As you can see, the right approach depends greatly on your Exchange/Active Directory/LAN setup.

Comment: Hi Dana, Your comment is very helpful. I did try to set up the SMTP like below      SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("10.21.80.174");
                client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                client.EnableSsl = true; but it still doesnt work. Any idea why?

Comment: client.UseDefaultCredentials will, as with EWS, send along the credentials of the running process/thread. So in a web application, that's going to be some un-privileged IIS application pool identity by default, or possibly a service account if that's how it's configured. Either way, it is that account that is being sent to SMTP. So as with EWS, you will either have to come up with a NetworkCredential (i.e. password), or permission the IIS identity to be allowed to send via SMTP.

Comment: Thanks Dana. I think it answers my question.